# Solving system of equations, is the exercise solution incorrect?

Tags: solution-verification, systems-of-equations

We are tasked with solving the following system:
$$C +D\ln(r_1)=U_1 $$
$$C +D\ln(r_2)=U_2 $$

When I solve for $D$ I find that $$D=\frac{U_1-U_2}{\ln(r_1)-\ln(r_2)} $$
But the solutions to the exercise say that $$D=\frac{U_2-U_1}{\ln(r_1)-\ln(r_2)} $$ Now, I have checked this several times and I don't really see what I am doing wrong, is the solution incorrect or am I mistaken?

EDIT: The only variables of interest are $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Plug your $D$ into one on your equations. Does it solve the equation, or not?

Comment: Looks like you're right.